# What to do after running osm2pgsql

Tags: postgresql

I must admit that I'm new when it comes to database administration, but I'm a little confused at the process of my getting my .osm.pbf file into tilemill.

I've run the osm2pgsql process on a .osm.pbf file, it ran, and said that it was completed.  I'm pretty sure that this file goes into PostGreSQL, but I'm unsure of how to access this.

Maybe my understanding of the process is completely skewed?

Not sure, but at this point I know that when I use "psql" in the terminal I'm able to use SQL commands, although I haven't set up any specific account information.

Comment: Also, I was using this tutorial for the download: https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-mac-quickstart/

Comment: probably more chance on stackoverflow on this one.

Comment: It's probably best to just start with the postgis and postgresql tutorials. You can connect to PostgreSQL using `psql`, or any PostgreSQL client driver or application. Many people use dedicated GIS applications that use PostgreSQL as a backend. To figure out which database within PostgreSQL your data went into, check the `osm2pgsql` manual to see what its default is. If it doesn't say, it'll probably be in a DB with the same name as the username you connected to.

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to pgAdmin III and connect to your database.

2) Check the tables if your table is populated and all is ok.

3) Go to QGis and create a PostgreSQL connection (on the left, the "Elephant Plus" icon).

4) Create a query layer using Database | DB Manager | SQL Window

5) F5 to run. Check "Load as New Layer" checkbox.

6) Select the "Unique ID column" - It's important and will not work if there's no unique ID. Select the Geometry column (must have one).

7) Click "Load Now!"

Done. You can now play with your data.